# How to handle multiple members of a C++ class simultaneously?

Tags: c++, python, class

I'm used to Python, and struggling to learn some C++. In Python, when I have a class with a "move" function, I can simply add its members to a list and iterate over the list like this:

```
for i in list:
    i.move(n)
```

Now, how is the corresponding thing done conveniently in C++?

Comment: "when I have a class ..., I can simply add its members to a list" Pretend your class is `struct S { int a; double b; }; S obj;` In your example, does your `list` contain `obj.a` and `obj.b`, or `obj` itself? The provided answers discuss the later option, but your wording suggests the former, which is considerably more difficult.  C++ does not support reflection, which is necessary to inspect the members of an arbitrary class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same in C++ by using pointers or reference to your objects.

If your class is `MyClass`, you could declare:

```
std::vector<MyClass*> list;
```

then add your objects to the list:

```
list.push_back(&objectOfMyClass); //-- for all of your objects
```

and finally:

```
std::vector<MyClass*>::iterator itr;
for (itr = list.begin(); itr != list.end(); ++itr) {
   (*itr)->myMethod(...);
}
```

I have used `std::vector` for simplicity in allocating objects (it grows automatically) and to get an iterator, which should be known to you, but you could do the same just by using a plain array, if you prefer.

Comment: It would be worth mentioning why you are using a pointer in a vector, especially since the vector is designed to contain objects not pointers (in general).

Comment: This sounds convincing, but the first line gives me a cryptic error: template argument for 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator' uses local type 'main()::MyClass'. And the second line gives me "request for member 'push_back' in 'list', which is of non-class type 'int'". I guess it's simply not my day, so I'll just stop bothering you now.

Comment: Would you post the code you are trying to compile? It seems to me that you tried to define `MyClass` inside of `main()`... (read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876048/why-can-i-define-structures-and-classes-within-a-function-in-c). define it outside and everything should be fine... also note the edit I did to the code...

Comment: That was indeed the problem, I actually discovered it by myself shortly after having posted the message. Seems like I've been spoiled by the convenience of Python, didn't know it can matter _where_ you define classes... Well, now you've answered how I can affect several **functions** (which is what I asked in the OP), but to expand the question, how would I change some **value** of all class members? Can I do it directly in the for loop somehow without having to make a separate function for it?

Comment: Instead of calling the function, do the assignment: `(*itr)->member = value;`; `member` must be public for this to work, but actually accessing members directly is not considered good practice in C++...

Answer (score 1):

You can get your python like syntax using boost foreach

Since you probably want to use virtual functions this means you will have objects of different types in your container. This means you need a container of pointers, so we go to boost again fro boost::ptr_vector (ptr_list works the same way).

Then we can get a simple application like this:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

#define   foreach   BOOST_FOREACH

class MyBase {public: virtual ~MyBase() {} virtual void move(int x) = 0;}

int main()
{
    boost::ptr_vector<MyBase>    data  /*= fillData()*/;

    foreach(MyBase& i, data)
    {
         i.move(4);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//create a vector of int's (basically a container, like an array)
vector<int> v;
//insert item into vector    
v.push_back(12);

//create an iterator that points to the first item in the vector    
vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin();


// move through the vector from begin() to end(), printing each item to console.    
for (; iter != v.end(); iter++)
{
    std::cout << *iter;
}
```

Comment: So I can only use integers as vector items, not the class members themselves? What does the integer represent, and how do I refer to a function (or value) of all class members?

Comment: `int` is being used as the type of element stored in the vector for demonstration purposes. You can store anything that meets a few basic requirements (basically, types that behave like values and can be copied as such), but everything in the vector needs to be the same type. `iter` *behaves like* a pointer to an element; so you can access a member function like `iter->foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
list<myobj>::iterator Iterator;
for(Iterator = mydata.begin(); Iterator != mydata.end(); Iterator++)
 {
  (*Iterator).move(n);
 }
```

Comment: Why not: `Iterator->move(n);`