# pushing structure variable in queue

Tags: c++, struct, queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    struct process {
        int burst;
        int ar;
    };
    int x=4;
    process a[x];
    queue <string> names; /* Declare a queue */
    names.push(a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to pushing struct variable in queue but its not taking it and gives errors

```
no matching function for #include queue and invalid argument
```

how can I do that?

Comment: This is certainly a completely wrong approach: `process a[x];`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so u are saying i cant even create an array of structure?
Because it does not give error {process a[x]} i have tested and also assigned burst and arrival to whole array and printed its working fine.

Comment: You can but that isn't how you create an array.  What would the size even be?

Comment: You can do that, but your approach (to solve whatever) is pretty nonsensical and wrong (there's no, or just undefined memory allocated for `a`, snce `x` is uninitialized).

Comment: @Scott size is x which is i forget to initialize but in the other code where m working there is no error about process's array.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes i see, but in the other code where i'm working i have initialized it and works fine just forget to initialize here. But can u help me with my problem which is about queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is a strongly typed language. In the line `names.push(a[1]);` you are trying to push a `struct` (from your `process a[x];` array) into a `queue<string>`. Your struct is not a `string`, so the compiler will emit an error. You at least need a `queue<process>`.

Other issues: variable length arrays are not standard C++ (`process a[x];`). Use a `std::vector<process>` instead. Here is some simple example that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    struct process // move this outside of main() if you don't compile with C++11 support
    {
        int burst;
        int ar;
    };
    vector<process> a;
    // insert two processes
    a.push_back({21, 42});
    a.push_back({10, 20});

    queue <process> names; /* Declare a queue */
    names.push(a[1]); // now we can push the second element, same type
    return 0; // no need for this, really
}
```

**EDIT**

Locally defined classes/structs used to instantiate templates are valid only in C++11 and later, see e.g. [Why can I define structures and classes within a function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876048/why-can-i-define-structures-and-classes-within-a-function-in-c) and the answers within. If you don't have access to a C++11 compliant compiler, then move your `struct` definition outside of `main()`.

Comment: it is giving 4 errors at (vector<process> a;) 
1.trying to instantiate 'template<class> class std::allocator
2. Invalid argument

Comment: Compile with `-std=c++11`

Comment: thanks it really worked. I'm wondering if u tell me please why did u use a.push_back({21,42}) in the code. what is this ?

Comment: `{21, 42}` creates a temporary object of type `struct process`, which is then inserted in the vector via the `push_back` vector's member function. See e.g. [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) for a tutorial about `std::vector`.