# Use of template inside macros

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on code to create class of different name based on macro argument. The problem is that this class uses template. This is my code

```
#define CHECK(exp,from,to) \
template<bool T> \
class _##to{ }; \
\
template<> class _##to<true>{ \
public: \
     _##to(...); \
};\
\
class _##from{ };\
_##to<exp>(_##from);\
```

but i am getting this error:

```
error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope|
```

So, if i can't use template at block scope then is there any solution for this??

EDITED:

This is my whole code:

```
#define CHECK(exp,from,to) \
template<bool T> \
class _##to{ }; \
\
template<> class _##to<true>{ \
public: \
     _##to(...); \
};\
\
class _##from{ };\
_##to<exp>(_##from);\

template<class TO,class FROM>
void safe_cast(FROM&){
     CHECK(sizeof(FROM)>=sizeof(TO),FROM,TO); //For calling macro
}

int main(){
     float f=90;
     safe_cast<int>(f);
}
```

Comment: How do you call that macro?

Comment: If you use gcc, run with with `-E` key to see how your preprocessed source look like. I think the error would make more sense then.

Comment: Based on the edit: you cannot create template class inside a function. You should do that outside of the function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876048/why-can-i-define-structures-and-classes-within-a-function-in-c).

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Looks like you are writing your own testing framework.
IMO you are wasting your time since you are not capable to write something better than `gtest`. Also defining a template by macro is pointless. First you should define a template than macro should use this template.

Comment: @MarekR Well i am just a learner. Doesn't know anything about `gtest`. I was studying template and came up with concept **Compile-time assertion**. So i was just working on my code to give compile time error with a message on wrong cast. Hence, I wanted classes of my name i.e from argument, just to make it more readable.

Comment: "Compile-time assertion" - since C++11 you have a static assertions, so there is no need to write some complex templates and macros. There is also a `Boost.StaticAssert`.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks a lot for that. Its really helpful.